# How to automatically query a webpage and parse the data which is displayed on the page and store it in a database

Tags: java, javascript, database, web-services, analytics

I tried searching a lot but could not found a specific answer to my problem.
I am trying build an analytical software which fetches data from a website by querying it with different samples of data.
For Example:
consider this URL: http://onlineresult.msbte.org.in/ore201401/
now here you had to provide a seat number / Enrollment number in the box. As soon as you click search it will display the result of the student.

Now what i want to do is to automate the task by means of a software and retrieve the data for say N number of students. This data will further be used for analytical purpose.

SAMPLE CASE:
ENTER:- 586124 in seat number box and click on search.

You will now get a page http://onlineresult.msbte.org.in/ore201401/index.php/public_display/result 
which displays the result of a student.

So I want to fetch this result from page and store it in database.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Selenium WebDriver to:

- access to the page
- provide the seat number
- click on the button
- wait until is displayed the element that contains the value
- read it contains

However, it is a simple website, so it may be faster to obtain the results using HtmlUnit like is explained in some answers to this question: [How to programmatically access web page in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549890/how-to-programmatically-access-web-page-in-java)